# notification disappears after showing

Tags: android, notifications

We have code similar to the following in our app

```
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, id.toInt(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT)
    val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx, Channel.TEST_CHANNEL.channelId)
    builder.setTicker(tickerText)
            .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
            .setContentText(contentText)
            .setVibrate(vibrate)
            .setSmallIcon(icon)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setLights(-0xff0100, 300, 1000)
            .setSound(uri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(contentText))
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_notification, ctx.getString(R.string.notification), piAction)

    val notification = builder.build()
    val nf = ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    nf.notify(NOTIFICATION_TAG, id.toInt(), notification)
}
```

Starting recently we noticed that notifications on some device running Android 8+ started disappearing briefly after being shown, without user's interaction. Setting `auto-cancel` to `false` helps, but the user experience degrades.

The `id` is a unique item id from the database. This may be important thing to note - technically we can have a notification with such `id` be shown, removed/canceleld by user, and later some time used again for a similar notification with the same id. Can this be the reason?

Comment: What is your current android version, 8.0 or 8.1?

Comment: 8.1, but have user complain on 8.0

Comment: Did you create a _NotificationChannel_ ?

Comment: yes, without it the notification is not shown at all. While the problem is - it is shown and after some time removed from the statusbar

Comment: Had similar issue - I was calling cancelAll somewhere else in the app.

Comment: @ArtursVancans thanks for comment, but we don't have 'cancelAll', only cancel with the same id. The bug hasn't appeared for some time already.

Answer (score 1):

We've updated the support libs and tried the following method on builder for luck:

```
 builder.setTicker(tickerText)
        ...
        .setTimeoutAfter(-1)
        ...
```

Setting this param to a positive value delayed the notification disappearing by that amount of time (so it did affect). Thus we tried a negative number, the notifications seem to stay there now.

*I couldn't find any reasonable documentation explaining this, so this answer is not 100%, but keeping it here for now for others to try and see if it helps them*.

Answer (score 0):

Disable your application from auto optimize from battery optimization setting in android OREO. Notification will stay as long as you want

Answer (score -1):

Only thing I found uncertain is **NotificationCompat.Builder**

Android oreo now uses **Notification.Builder** instead of **NotificationCompat.Builder**.

Might be you have to check android version like:

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
         //Use Notification.Builder         
         } else {
         // Use NotificationCompat.Builder.
         }
```

I don't think unique id will be an issue for disappearing notification.

Google has created open source sample for this new changes. Please refer to it for more info.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-NotificationChannels

Comment: What do you mean by `Android oreo now uses Notification.Builder instead of NotificationCompat.Builder.`? There has always been a framework version and a support version. Support version only exists so you don't have to write this if-else nonsense.

Answer (score -1):

.setAutoCancel(false)

May be it will work for you.